# WPF Is there a way to get the container for an item on a selectionchanged event?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Normally I would either search the visual tree or use the itemcontainergenerator to get the container. However, in wpf hierachicaldatatemplates have an itemcontainergenerator for each level, and it doesn't appear as if selectionchanged's event arguments contain the actual parent item or the container of the item.

I can code around this by triggering on mousedown of an actual treeviewitem. However, it seems odd that I can't use the selectionchanged event of the treeview to access the treeview's itemcontainers around the selected item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the TreeView declaration:

```
<TreeView Name="myTreeView" TreeViewItem.Selected="OnItemSelected"
ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource myHierarchicalData}}"/>
```

OnItemSelected handler:

```
private void OnItemSelected(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    myTreeView.Tag = e.OriginalSource;
}
```

Here is the code to access TreeViewItem:

```
if (myTreeView.SelectedItem != null)
{
    TreeViewItem selectedTVI = myTreeView.Tag as TreeViewItem;

    // add your code here
}
```